# Zoomable treemap with tooltips at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

The [zoomable treemap](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html) is great, but there is one feature that I think would make it even greater. When hovering the mouse around the rectangles (either before or after zooming), there is no easy way to know where in the hierarchy the rectangle is, and what its size is.

I am new to D3, but am wondering what changes I would need to make to have a hovering tooltip like the one shown below working. Is this a relatively easy fix, or would it take a big change to the source code to have it? Where could I get started?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register another event handler when the cells enter, right after the click-zoom function. In the example you linked the relevant code would be:

```
var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(nodes)
 .enter().append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "cell")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
  .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });
```

To this you could add on another handler for mouseover, and within that function, walk up the tree, recording the name of each parent node until there are no more parent nodes, and then write the list to your popover. Lets assume just for the sake of this example that you set up your tooltip as shown in your image, and you gave it an id of `tooltip`.

Then you could use a handler like this:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d) {
  // this variable will be used in a loop to store the current node being inspected
  var currentNode = d;
  // this array will hold the names of each subsequent parent node
  var nameList = [currentNode.name];
  // as long as the current node has a parent...
  while (typeof currentNode.parent === 'object') {
    // go up a level in the hierarchy
    currentNode = currentNode.parent;
    // add the name to the beginning of the list
    nameList.unshift(currentNode.name);
  }
  // now nameList should look like ['flare','animate','interpolate']
  //  join the array with slashes (as you have in your example)
  nameList = nameList.join('/');
  // now nameList should look like 'flare/animate/interpolate'
  //  use this to set the tooltip text
  $('#tooltip').text('Mouse hovering ' + nameList + '. Cell size = ' + d.area);
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean, and well explained.

Comment: Thanks. This is great. By the way, based on this idea, I tried adding a stroke of a specific color around the cell on mouseover (to clearly highlight the extension of the cell). More specifically, I tried adding the following to the end of the `"mouseover"` function: `d3.select(this).attr("stroke:pink")` without luck. Any thoughts why it doesn't work?

Comment: It's just a syntax issue. The attribute name and value are passed as two separate arguments to `.attr()`. Try it like this: `d3.select(this).attr('stroke', 'pink')`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. One problem I have is that `this` includes the text in the cell as well, so changing the stroke affects the svg box and the text inside of it. It would be great if I could just target the `svg:rect` and not `svg:text`. Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: I think I got it: `select(this).select("rect")`. Thanks!