# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token with mouseover event in D3 Treemap

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events, mouseover, treemap

I am working on putting together a zoomable treemap using D3. I'm starting with basic code at https://gist.github.com/vibster/3257874. I'm including the git for the whole code, but will include the relevant section below.

To the `cell` variable, I am adding a mouse over function from this previous answer: [Zoomable treemap with tooltips at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419101/zoomable-treemap-with-tooltips-at-the-bottom) that should provide a tool tip on hover.

```
  var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
              .data(nodes)
              .enter().append("svg:g")
              .attr("class", "cell")
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
              .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });
```

This results in this code for the variable cell:

```
var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
              .data(nodes)
              .enter().append("svg:g")
              .attr("class", "cell")
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
              .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });
              .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                      // this variable will be used in a loop to store the current node being inspected
                      var currentNode = d;
                      // this array will hold the names of each subsequent parent node
                      var nameList = [currentNode.name];
                      // as long as the current node has a parent...
                      while (typeof currentNode.parent === 'object') {
                        // go up a level in the hierarchy
                        currentNode = currentNode.parent;
                        // add the name to the beginning of the list
                        nameList.unshift(currentNode.name);
                      }
                      // now nameList should look like ['flare','animate','interpolate']
                      //  join the array with slashes (as you have in your example)
                      nameList = nameList.join('/');
                      // now nameList should look like 'flare/animate/interpolate'
                      //  use this to set the tooltip text
                      $('#tooltip').text('Mouse hovering ' + nameList + '. Cell size = ' + d.area);
                }
```

Unfortunately, this results in the treemap not showing up at all. I did some digging in the Chrome Console and am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

I'm completely new to Javascript and D3 so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` is probably caused by Javascript files which are loaded in your basic code example: https://gist.github.com/vibster/3257874
These files in the header contains bad url to source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/treemap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/hierarchy.js"></script>
```

If you open the url e.g. of the first source It contains HTML github page, not Javascript source code. You could use [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/) to get raw Javascript files with proper headers. In addition, the two lines mentioned above are useless because `treemap` and `hierarchy` are also defined in the file loaded by this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
```

I created the jsfiddle with your code (without unnecessary 2 lines) and added the element `<div id="tooltip"></div>` which contains the tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/usxcop8d/. You could see the tooltip beneath the treemap on mouseover treemap tiles.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about the two lines of code. I see why you added the div tag. When I try to combine the JSfiddle back down to a single HTML file with the CSS and Javascript embedded, the tool tip doesn't show up. Any advice?

Comment: I can't edit my comment, but I did find it was a javascript error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` on the tooltip line

Comment: @user2242044 The tooltip example  also uses jQuery library. You should add it to the header (below or above the d3.v2.js). The source is e.g. here: `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js`.

Comment: Thanks, how did you know that? and how can I see which scripts are being referenced in a fiddle?

Comment: @user2242044 In the left menu tab `Frameworks & Extensions`, there is selected jQuery 1.11.0. You use it in the line `$('#tooltip').text(...`. Then in the tab `External Resources ` there is loaded library d3.js